# Porque me sale Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python

Estructura:

> _Archivos Python
> __dist
> __moperaciones.egg-info
> __calculos
> ____modulooperaciones.py
> ____Nueva carpeta
> ______modulo_uso_operaciones.py

Usé el IDLE default de Python para crear el archivo *modulo_uso_operaciones.py*

```py
1 from calculos.modulooperaciones import *
2 elevar(3,4)
```

> (el código from es remarcado con una línea roja ,al poner el curso sobre este me señala **Unable to import 'calculos.modulooperaciones'pylint(import-error**)

,en el cual importé un paquete simple que hice ,y funciona perfectamente cuando corre;pero cuando abri el mismo archivo (*modulo_uso_operaciones.py*) en VSC y luego lo hice correr ,me aparece el siguiente error:

```py
Exception has occurred:ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'calculos'
  File "C:\Users\Mario Mani\Desktop\Archivos Python\calculos\Nueva carpeta\modulo_uso_operaciones.py", line 1, in <module>
    from calculos.modulooperaciones import *
```

No entiendo el porqué de esto si el archivo abierto es el mismo ,y aun asi solo funciona en el IDLE default.
Cuál podria ser el problema que cause esto?
GRacias de antemano

Comment: No nos has mostrado el código, ni la estructura de directorio, ni el mensaje de error completo (donde seguro dice qué módulo no encontro). Sin más información, imposible responder

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer un archivo vacio en tu carpeta de modulos llamado `__init__.py` este archivo es que marca tu carpeta como modulos de python y otra es que no ejecutes tus script en la misma carpeta de los modulos.

aca puedes leer mas acerca de **init**.py  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)